# Android MediaPlayer supported MJPEG

Tags: android

Is Android MediaPlayer supported the MJPEG format.

```
1                        path = "http://cif12.nfreeway.gov.tw/live-view/mjpg/video.cgi camera=187&1168226466841";
2               mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camsurface);
3               holder = mPreview.getHolder();
4               holder.addCallback(this);
5               holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
6               mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
7               mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
8               mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
9               mMediaPlayer.prepare();
10              mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
11              mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
12              mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
13              mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
14              mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

on line number 9 code exit without any exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of [supported media codecs](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) for Android. MJPEG is not on the list.

Also, if you examine LogCat (via `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse), you may find some warnings or errors.